# PHP: How to convert special composed character from UTF-8 to Latin 3

Tags: php, character-encoding, utf8-decode

I am trying to export data from my database (UTF-8) to CSV wich is to be opened on MS Excel (Latin 3). For that I am using

```
$data[$keyLine][$keyField] = utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($curField, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

The problem is that my data is in french, and includes words such as ***cœur***. All data exported is looking fine except that composed character œ, where I am getting a question mark (***cœur*** is converted to ***c?ur***), how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply check that codeset. [Maybe here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-3) that character does not seem to exists in that set. However is does seem to be supported in `ISO-8859-15`, `ISO-8859-16` and  `Windows-1252`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RiggsFolly 's tip, I managed to do it with `iconv`

```
$data[$keyLine][$keyField] = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", html_entity_decode($curField, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

Windows-1252 was the only charset that worked, thou. Neither ISO-8859-15 or 16 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this....

> $data[$keyLine][$keyField] = htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities(trim( stripslashes( $curField ) ), ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8", true));